# Can't add data to the Firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add data such as '*Image*', '*Name*', '*Price*' to my Firebase db. My setDoc doesn't seem to work and I don't get any errors. This is how my database looks like ( the first value has been added manually )

[image]

**I have changed the permissions as well**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   import { db, storage } from './../../config/config';
   import { ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage';
   import { getDocs, collection, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
   import { ItemsList, AddForm } from './shopStyle'
   import { set } from "firebase/database";;
   import { v4 } from 'uuid';

   export const Shop = () => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
   const itemsRef = collection(db, "items");

   // New item states
   const [newItemName, setNewItemName] = useState("");
   const [newItemPrice, setNewItemPrice] = useState(0);
   const [newItemImage, setNewItemImage] = useState(null);


   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchData = async () => {
       try {
    const data = await getDocs(itemsRef);
    const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));
    setItems(filteredData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
fetchData();
  }, []);

  const addItems = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

if(newItemImage == null) return;
const imageRef = ref(storage,`items/${newItemImage.Name + v4()}`);
uploadBytes(imageRef, newItemImage).then(() =>{
  alert("image uploaded");
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
})

/* set(ref(itemsRef, 'items/' ), {
  Image: newItemImage,
    Name: newItemName,
    Price: newItemPrice
}); */
try {
  await setDoc(itemsRef, {
    Image: newItemImage,
    Name: newItemName,
    Price: newItemPrice,
  });

  // Clear input fields after successful addition
  setNewItemImage("");
  setNewItemName("");
  setNewItemPrice(0);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
} 
  };  

     return (
<div>
  <AddForm onSubmit={addItems}>
    <input
      accept="image/*"
      id="icon-button-file"
      type="file"
      onChange={(e) => setNewItemImage(e.target.files[0])}
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="name"
      value={newItemName}
      onChange={(e) => setNewItemName(e.target.value)}
    />
    <input
      type="number"
      placeholder="price"
      value={newItemPrice}
      onChange={(e) => setNewItemPrice(e.target.value)}
    />
    <button onClick={addItems}>Add</button>
  </AddForm>
  <ItemsList>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <img src={item.Image} alt={item.Name} />
        <h1>{item.Name}</h1>
        <h4>{item.Price}</h4>
      </div>
    ))}
  </ItemsList>
</div>
 );
};
```

I have tried different methods that don't involve "addDoc" to add to the db but it seems that none of them are working. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

P.S. After running the code using addDoc I've got this error which makes no sense since I am using the right data...

*FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Reference object (found in field Image in document items/frn98qT4Te2e2VnCviuW)*

Comment: Instead of setting the image object to `Image` of setDoc you have to get the downloadURL for the uploaded image and then save the downloadURL to the Image of setDoc refer this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of your code boils down to this:

```
const itemsRef = collection(db, "items");
...
await setDoc(itemsRef, {
  Image: newItemImage,
  Name: newItemName,
  Price: newItemPrice,
});
```

You can't call `setDoc` on a [`CollectionReference` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference). You'll want to use `addDoc` instead, so that it adds a new document to the collection.

Comment: I have tried both setDoc and addDoc but unfortunately none of them work so far...

Comment: My answer explains why the `setDoc` call that you posted in the code in your question doesn't work.